# Can I use USB foot controller for tablet or maybe you know a better idea?

Tags: software

can I use this with Android tablet via USB https://www.thomann.de/gb/keith_mcmillen_12_step.htm or do anyone know any Bluetooth foot switch with about 7-12 pedals? I'm planing to use it with MobileSheets Pro. 1 pedal to play/stop track, 2 for previous/next song, 2 for page turning and 2 for volume (using Tincore Keymapper). I wasn't able to find more than 6 Bluetooth pedals. Could you suggest something for my demand?

Comment: Historically, this site has opined that software/hardware recommendations are off topic. It's a good question, but I don't know whether this site would consider this "on topic" or not.

Comment: Problem with Bluetooth is that is latency (a gap in response time) and may not be great for what you need.